# In the sentence, 'Honor your old teacher', should the noun be definite or indefinite? (Greek)

Tags: greek, articles

In the sentence, 'Honor your old teacher', should the noun be definite or indefinite? I'm tempted to say definite.

> τίμᾱ τὸν παλαίον διδάσκαλον σου.

But the one doubt I have is that there is no definite article 'the' in the English. I think this reveals that I have a less-than-perfect understanding of definite and indefinite nouns. Would 'your old teacher' be definite, because the noun is referring to a specific person? Is it more a matter of specificity, than whether the article 'the' is used?

Comment: A couple of accent corrections: τὸν παλαι**ὸ**ν διδάσκαλ**ό**ν σου (second accent because of the enclitic). (τὸν σὸν παλαιὸν διδάσκαλον sounds better to me, btw.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I would say, definite.

Greek uses definite articles somewhat differently than English does. In English, the definite article is used before a definite noun, **unless** the noun is proper or modified by a pronoun.

- "the tent"
- "my tent"
- "that tent"
- "Socrates"

In Greek, the definite article is used before definite nouns, **even if** the noun is proper or modified by a pronoun, or **any** nouns which don't change their form (to show their case).

- ἡ σκηνή
- **ἡ ἐμὴ** σκηνή
- **ἐκείνη ἡ** σκηνή
- **ὁ** Σωκράτης (*)

In your situation, it sounds like there's one particular teacher who deserves to be honored: you're not just honoring every teacher you happen across. This is a perfect place to use the definite article.

The Greek definite article can also function as a non-emphatic possessive. So *ἡ σκηνή* could also mean **his** tent, or **your** tent, or **their** tent, and so on. So in your example you could get away without using a possessive pronoun: *ὁ παλαιὸς διδάσκαλος* in this context would clearly refer to **your** teacher, rather than someone else's. But adding *σός* puts considerably more emphasis on that fact.

If you're interested, [this page](http://inthesaltshaker.com/drills/article.htm#SemFunc) provides more information on the semantics of the definite article. It's a very interesting and complicated topic; many papers have been written about the connotations of *θεός* versus *ὁ θεός* in John 1:1.

(*) With proper names, the definite article isn't mandatory. It's used generally for people who would be recognized immediately such as Socrates (if I mention "Socrates" you probably won't ask "which one?"), or people who have been mentioned earlier in the conversation. [The aforementioned link](http://inthesaltshaker.com/drills/article.htm#SemFunc) has more information on this as well.

Comment: +1. A couple small spelling corrections: ἡ ἐμ**ὴ** σκηνή, Σ**ω**κράτης, παλαι**ὸ**ς διδάσκαλος. Btw, though the definite article with proper names is common, it isn't obligatory -- Σωκράτης without ὁ is also correct.

Comment: @TKR Fixed, thanks! (And added a note about proper names without articles.)